# Loading Thickbox Gallery Slideshow

Tags: thickbox, image-gallery

I'm using the Thickbox "Gallery Images" example http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/#examples to show a slideshow for a group of photos which works perfectly, except that I also want to have a button that says 'Start Slideshow' that will open Thickbox and display the first photo in the slideshow that is tagged under the group 'rel="slideshow"'. Here is what the first image in the slideshow looks like:

```
<a href="image1.jpg" title="Image Title 1" class="thickbox" rel="slideshow"><img src="image1.jpg" width="150" border="0" alt="Image Title 1"></a>
```

Any ideas what the href link should look like for the 'Start Slideshow' button to accomplish this? I tried a bunch of approaches and none seem to get the job done.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching I finally found the answer:

http://codylindley.com/thickboxforum/comments.php?DiscussionID=946&page=1

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: As a general rule, you should avoid link-only answers, for example in this case when the link you've added no longer contains the content you saw 4 years ago.